# I got this error everytime when i try "gradle clean" in any project

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I am getting below error when i try to gradle clean in any react native project.

I am using:

- Mac M1
- Gradle v8.0.2
- Node v16.19.1
- Android SDK & Android NDK
- NPM v8.19.3

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script ‘/Project-name/node_modules/react-native/react.gradle' line: 241

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
   > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 54s
```

I want to get to know what is causing error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.